# taut foliations and the existence of total transversals

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, foliations

A codimension one foliation $\cal F$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is *taut* if every leaf of $\cal F$ meets a closed transversal (i.e., a simple closed curve that is everywhere transversal to the leaves of the foliation). Is it true that a taut foliation admits a closed transversal $\gamma$ that meets *all* leafs of the foliation?

(I've seen such a curve $\gamma$ being referred to as a total transversal).

Comment: Ahem, you probably intend $M$ to be connected? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  You can find a proof in Calegari's book, "Foliations and the Geometry of
3–Manifolds", lemma 4.26.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I wonder if the same results holds for non-compact M.

Comment: This is false for non-compact $M$ (interpreting $\gamma$ in this case to be an embedded line), since the leaf space of foliations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be non-Hausdorff. Such examples might also be in Calegari's book.

Comment: This completely answers my question. Thanks, I appreciate it.